# Issue on adding werror flag

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I am trying to add warning as error flag in my makefiles. But I am getting the following problem.

When I am compiling without adding the flag it is successful. But when I am adding Werror flag in some ".mk" files, compilation is failing with some error. But in the successful build log warning was not there for that source file(".c") which is throwing error now(Werror).

I am adding he following flags.

```
UN_CDEFS := -Wno-error=%
CDEFS   := -Wall -Werror -Wextra
SUB_CDEFS := -Wall -Werror -Wextra
```

So please suggest what might be the problem.

Comment: "compilation is failing with some error"?  *What* error?  Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `-Werror` does _not_ affect the warnings that are checked/looked for. Just whether the compiler returns error code [e.g. 1] on a warning (i.e. treat warning as error). So, either the basic build _was_ generating a warning that got suppressed/ignored/overlooked _or_ you added something else. My guess is that it's the `-Wextra` that is the issue as it tends to produce some false positives. So, try all of the following `-Wall`, `-Wall -Werror`, and `-Wall -Werror -Wextra` and note the differences. Also, how about `-Wall -Wextra`?

Comment: Thanks @CraigEstey. Actually in actual build log warning was not there for that file and i did not change any of the files. I only added these flags in makefiles. No source code change. Okay I will try -Wall _Werror (skip Wextra). I need Werror flag.

Comment: I _always_ use `-Werror` and have never had a problem. It just stops the build if there is a warning [that might be missed by visual inspection of the log]. _Side note:_ Some warnings are _only_ generated with the addition of `-O2`, due to how detection is implemented in a given compiler (e.g. I'm talking about `gcc`)

Comment: Hey @CraigEstey i tried the discussed option. But still it is same.

Comment: @CraigEstey But the warnings were not coming when it was without these flags. In the actual compilation warnings for this file are not there. So I am not able to understand why it is happening like this.

Answer (score 1):

*Caveat:* This isn't a complete answer because we need more information, but it would become [too] lengthy for more top comments like the ones I've already posted.

As you refine the problem and/or post more data, I can edit this answer accordingly. At a minimum, posting your actual makefiles might help, as well as, the actual final `cc` commands and the compiler warning/error output for the failing `.c` file [There may be multiple ones, but the single/first one should be sufficient].

Below are some detailed instructions on how to debug this, based on my own experience with such issues.

---

But, before I get to that, I'll hazard a guess. I notice that you're doing:

```
CDEFS := -Wall -Werror
```

[leaving off the `-Wextra` as you mentioned in a comment].

If this is done as [nearly] the first thing in the makefile, it's fine. However, if it occurs in the middle, you are *replacing* `CDEFS` with your own value. *If* a *prior* line in the makefile did (e.g.):

```
CDEFS = -Dwont_build_cleanly_without_this_option
```

then, when you add your line, that could be the issue, because this gets [effectively] removed. You might try this instead:

```
CDEFS += -Wall -Werror
```

This just appends to the existing symbol, so any prior value will be retained.

Also, the base makefile might have something like:

```
ifndef CDEFS
    CDEFS := -Dwont_build_cleanly_without_this_option
endif
```

---

Normally, `make` will output the full text of commands it executes to create targets. For compilation, this is (e.g.) `cc -c foo.c`.

Some fancier builds wrap the command in (e.g.) `@doit cc -c foo.c` where `doit` prints a message like `compiling foo.c ...` and only outputs the full command if there is an error. (e.g. the linux kernel build does this, IIRC). I'm assuming you *don't* have this, but if you do, there is usually a command line override such as `make VERBOSE=1`

So, there is some `.c` file somewhere that builds cleanly with the normal options but generates an error when extra compile options are added. Let's call this file `badnews.c`

What we want to see is the compilation command that `make` printed for `badnews.c` and the warning/error output for *two* cases:

1. without the extra options
2. with the extra options in various combinations

In particular, examining the case (1) command against the case (2) commands might show that options *other* than the `-W` are different. This indicates a makefile issue, similar to my "guess" above. You've said that [your equivalent of] case (1) is clean with no warnings, but, given the trouble you're having, it wouldn't hurt to double check.

You can cut and paste the case (1) `cc` command into a shell script and manually add the `-W` options. Watch out for things with spaces, such as `-DSTRING="foo bar"` in the makefile that may need extra quotes in a shell script.

---

To alleviate conflicts similar to yours, in my own makefiles I separate the symbols.

`DFLAGS` for all `-DFOO=1`

`COPTS` for `-g`, `-O2`, `-Wall`, `-fno-inline-functions`, etc.

Then, I either do:

```
CFLAGS := $(COPTS) $(DFLAGS)
```

Or:

```
%.o: %.c:
    cc -c $(COPTS) $(DFLAGS) $<
```

There are other ways to do this as well.

---

**UPDATE:**

> I am using following command to build: `emq PRODUCT=ASG >build_log_0508.log`

I'm unfamiliar with `emq`. I can't find a reference to it, except as "enterprise mail queue for JIRA", which [AFAICT] *may* be part of `cPanel`?

> Getting the following error on compilation: `prod/libs/app/app.c:720:5: error: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'free' [-Werror] free(tmp_dn);`

This is the smoking gun ...

I don't know what compiler you're using, or what OS/environment, but it appears to *not* flag this as a warning/error by default.

However, it *is* a bug in the source `app.c` that needs to be fixed. It was *correctly* flagged as a warning/error by the addition of `-Wall` and `-Werror`

*Note:* As I mentioned in my original answer, it *would* be helpful to have the final `cc` command line that produced this error [as well as the `cc` command when this file is *not* flagged].

I created a simple test case:

```
void
myfree(void *ptr)
{

    free(ptr);
}
```

Here, under `gcc`, I did `gcc -c test.c` and I get:

```
test.c: In function 'myfree':
test.c:5:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'free' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  free(ptr);
  ^
test.c:5:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'free'
test.c:5:2: note: include '<stdlib.h>' or provide a declaration of 'free'
```

So, `gcc` flags this by *default* [even *without* `-Wall` or `-Werror`]. But, *your* compiler does *not* unless it is given `-Wall`. This *could* occur if your compiler were `clang` and you also specified `-std=c89`

As I implied earlier, if you just specify `-Wall` but *not* `-Werror`, you should get the same warnings but they just won't stop the build. In a large build, they can be easily overlooked in the log [by a human (e.g.) me :-)].

Referring to the suggestions in my original answer, assuming that the `cc` commands between case (1) ["good"] and case (2) ["bad"] *only* differed by the addition of `-Wall`, the correct way to fix this is to edit `app.c` and add `#include <stdlib.h>` as part of the includes.

> Is there any problem with "SUB_CDEFS := -Wall -Werror"?

It will have similar problems/benefits as with `CDEFS`.

> I am adding at the end of the makefiles

This is all the more reason to use `+=` instead of `:=`. You might be "killing off" the `-std=c89` if that were specified somewhere.

---

**UPDATE #2:**

> It worked after doing `+=` instead of `:=`.

As I mentioned, using `:=` removed some critical compile options, that were specified elsewhere in the makefile(s).

But, once again, the source code has a *bug* and is *broken*. It was broken *before* you ever touched it. By adding `-Wall -Werror` using `:=`, you uncovered this bug, that previously was masked *incorrectly*. This is a *good* thing.

Using `+=` just sweeps the bug under the rug [again], by restoring some build options that were lost with `:=`. But, these "lost" build options were *wrong*. They allowed a genuine flaw in the C code to escape detection.

This is *not* about getting the build to work [with a workaround], but to fix the root cause of the build problems, which is to modify the C source code. There are probably other such C source code bugs and some may be more severe.

With the workaround to "fix" the build, you've now got a piece of built software that can *not* be trusted to *run* correctly. It could fail in intermittent ways on *your* system(s). Or, produce incorrect results. Or, allow your system to be hacked [and potentially expose you to legal liability] if you're putting this on a publicly facing site.

If you're not comfortable doing the source modification yourself, file a bug report with the original author of the software. The source code should have a `README` file, or `BUGS` file, or whatever that should outline a procedure for doing so.

> Just need one more clarification for what is the difference between `SUB_CDEFS`, `UN_CDEFS`, and `CDEFS`

It's completely arbitrary.

Software projects built with `make`, can often build multiple programs or libraries. These often are placed in subdirectories. Each such subdirectory often has its own `Makefile`.

To avoid needless duplication [and potential error], the parts that would be common to these makefiles are placed in a *single* makefile, often called a *rules* file [but it's just a makefile]. The individual makefiles then have a line like: `include ../common/rules.mk`

The rules file expects that certain symbols are defined that help guide it to build the targets for the given subdirectory.

`CDEFS` et. al. are an example of such symbols. Names that are descriptive of function are [should be] chosen. That is, `CDEFS` [probably] means "C definitions". The actual symbol names and their function depends upon the rules file. We *could* use the symbol `SHRONK` instead of `CDEFS`. That doesn't help much with understanding things, but if all makefiles were edited to change `CDEFS` to `SHRONK`, it would work.

For example, in other software, instead of `CDEFS`, a similar symbol might be named `CFLAGS` or `COPTS`. This is fairly common.

*Side note:* It's a bit moot at this point, but things would have gone much more smoothly and quickly if you had edited your question and posted the output `cc` commands and [some of] your makefiles as I had requested. You would have gotten *specific* answers in a matter of hours instead of general guidelines [that took several days].

So, without the rules file, it's not possible to tell. Only make a *guess*, based upon the names:

1. `CDEFS` -- global `cc` options for a subdirectories
2. `SUB_CDEF` -- `cc` options for *this* particular subdirectory
3. `UN_CDEFS` -- specify `-Ufoo` options

The particular software you are building may have documentation for this in a documentation file or in comments in one or more of the makefiles.

To understand this generally, there are many online guides to `make`. Under Linux, there are "info" files. So, try `info make`. Other systems have detailed manpages, so do `man make`

Comment: emq PRODUCT=ASG >build_log_0508.log                                                 Getting the following error on compilation                                                        prod/libs/app/app.c:720:5: error: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'free' [-Werror]
     free(tmp_dn);
     ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors

Comment: Is there any problem with "SUB_CDEFS := -Wall -Werror"?

Comment: One more thing.. I am adding at the end of the makefiles.

Comment: Hey Craig, Thanks a lot. It worked after doing += instead of := . Just need one more clarification for what is the difference between SUB_CDEFS, UN_CDEFS, and CDEFS

Comment: If you have any link for understanding all these then please tell.Thnaks.